# Recommendation for a lightweight midi editor/sequencer?

Tags: midi

I'm looking for a simple midi editor/sequencer. I need it to look up what's inside the midi file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MusE](http://muse-sequencer.org/) is a MIDI/Audio sequencer with recording and editing capabilities. MusE aims to be a complete multitrack virtual studio for Linux, it is published under the GNU General Public License.<sup>[MusE](http://muse-sequencer.org/)</sup>

MusE is part of Ubuntu Studio.